# What is the difference between these 2 setCount functions that are seemingly doing the same thing

Tags: reactjs

So I have the super basic count function done in react hook as the following

```
function App() {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
    

  return (
      <>
      <h1>count: {count}</h1>

      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>click me</button>
      </>
  );

}
```

As you can see every time click on the button it increments the `count` value by 1 with a simple `setCount(count + 1)`. However when I tried to do a stopwatch like the following

```
const Stopwatch = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCount(count + 1);
    }, 100);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);


  return <h3>Stopwatch: {count.toFixed(1)}</h3>;
};
```

and my `count` value was stuck at `1.0`.Now someone told me to change the `setCount(count + 1)` to `setCount(count => count + 0.1);` and it worked, but I'm still confused as why my previous code didn't work. Can someone explain to me why

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Explanation for `setCount(count => count + 0.1)` :

This maybe because of the batching mechanism of react. setState call can be batched for the performance gains.

setState is asynchronous. this allows to have multiple set state calls and avoid unnecessary re-renders of the whole dom.

Thats the reason why you can't access the state right after the update.

**Solution :**

If you're value is dependant upon the previous value , always use the callback function that setState provides.
for e.g., `setCount(count => count + 0.1)`

react will the get you the freshest value and expect you to merge it to return the merged state.

Comment: so `useEffect` clean up function will run every time the `count` value changed ?

Comment: The official documentation indicates that it runs when the component gets unmounted but also states that in every render useEffect gets re-run and so does the clean up function. So i guess that validates my answer to your question is not correct. so I'll give updated answer explaining why setState callback is useful in this scenario.